# Is there a way to import text data from a text file into a html table

Tags: php, html

I have to load a text file into an HTML table and have no idea how to do it.

This is my document I have to put the table in and an example of the text document.

```
<?php # Script 3.4 - index.php
$page_title = 'Climate Data For All Cities';
include ('./includes/header.html');
?>
<h1 id="mainhead">Climate Data For All Cities</h1>
<p>There are currently 80 cities.</p>
(table will go here)
<?php
include ('./includes/footer.html');
?>
```

Text document:

```
Lander  WY  5557    99  -35 109 140 67
Milwaukee   WI  672 98  -7  79  177 124
Seattle WA  400 94  12  55  233 163
Spokane WA  2356    98  -16 95  187 112
Burlington  VT  332 91  6   54  217 168
Norfolk VA  24  98  19  85  145 117
Richmond    VA  164 101 16  105 165 115
Salt Lake City  UT  4221    103 -11 129 152 86
Dallas  TX  551 106 10  130 152 89
Houston TX  96  104 19  73  166 94
San Antonio TX  788 102 16  90  165 83
Memphis TN  258 101 12  121 151 112
Huron   SD  1281    100 -30 121 147 80
Rapid City  SD  3162    106 -30 106 127 95
```

Comment: what's the separators spaces? or tabs? you should look at the csv functions in php, it can work with other separators than just commas

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882108/getting-data-from-text-file-and-display-it-in-html-table

Answer (score 1):

I am more of a JS sort of person but you can integrate this into PHP to work seamlessly. You will need to add the following to your head tags

```
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="text.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

The Text file you provided was saved as "text.txt" located at the same level as index html, and the following text.js script.

text.txt contains the following

```
Lander  WY  5557    99  -35 109 140 67
Milwaukee   WI  672 98  -7  79  177 124
Seattle WA  400 94  12  55  233 163
Spokane WA  2356    98  -16 95  187 112
Burlington  VT  332 91  6   54  217 168
Norfolk VA  24  98  19  85  145 117
Richmond    VA  164 101 16  105 165 115
Salt Lake City  UT  4221    103 -11 129 152 86
Dallas  TX  551 106 10  130 152 89
Houston TX  96  104 19  73  166 94
San Antonio TX  788 102 16  90  165 83
Memphis TN  258 101 12  121 151 112
Huron   SD  1281    100 -30 121 147 80
Rapid City  SD  3162    106 -30 106 127 95
```

You should have the following HTML in your body (can do it in php)

```
<h1>Text File reader</h1>
<button type="button" name="button" id="fileReadButton">LOAD</button>
<table id="textFileContentTable">
  <thead>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>High</th>
    <th>Low</th>
    <th>Days Clear</th>
    <th>Days Cloudy</th>
    <th>Days with Precip</th>
    <th>Days With Snow</th>
  </thead>
</table>
```

and finally, here is the script to get the data from the text file on click of the button, to fill in the table.

```
$().ready(function(){
 function populateTable(filePath){
    // get request for the file
    $.get(filePath, function(response){
      let rows = response.split("\n");
      // getting each row of the text file
      for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
        var validRowData = [];
        var rowData = rows[i].split(" ");
        // getting the data for the row
        for (var z = 0; z < rowData.length; z++) {
          if(rowData[z] == ""){
          }else{
            validRowData.push(rowData[z]);
          }
          // sanitising the strings like San Antonio and Rapid City
          if(validRowData.length == 9){
            validRowData[0] = validRowData[0] + " " + validRowData[1];
            validRowData.splice(1, 1);
          }
        }
        // creating the row template, iterating through the valid data to create TDs
        var rowTemplate = "<tr>";
        for (var j = 0; j < validRowData.length; j++) {
          rowTemplate += "  <td> " + validRowData[j] + " </td> ";
        }
        rowTemplate += "   </tr>";
        // appending it to the table
        $('#textFileContentTable').append(rowTemplate);
      }
    });
  }

  // onclick of the button, load the table
  $('#fileReadButton').click(function(){
    populateTable('./text.txt');
  });
});
```

Comment: How would I get each number into diffrent columns. With these headings for each columns.                                                                                                <th>Location</th>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>High</th>
    <th>Low</th>
    <th>Days Clear</th>
    <th>Days Cloudy</th>
    <th>Days with Precip</th>
    <th>Days With Snow</th>

Comment: Updating my solution now, you just need to change the <th> elements

Comment: Solution has been updated, if this solves your problem please vote :)

Comment: This is absurdly complicated and makes no sense to do it client-side.

Comment: I disagree, it's a tiny file, no mention of a larger file (scope of your question is incredibly limited), if you want a server side, copy the logic into php form.

Comment: The code literally just gets rows, then columns, then sanitises the first field, then populates the table.

Comment: If it were a basic CSV format, or a there was consistence to the way the data was delimited it would be simpler

Comment: I am rewriting the function on the train home to be PHP only :)

Answer (score 0):

Running the following PHP script:

```
<?php
function fixCities($better_row){
  $res = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$better_row));
  $pieces = explode(" ",$res);
  $num = count($pieces);

  switch( $num )
  {
  case 9:
     $temp = array($pieces[0]."&nbsp;". $pieces[1]);
     array_splice($pieces, 0, 2,$temp);
     break;
  case 10: 
     $temp = array($pieces[0]."&nbsp;" .$pieces[1] . "&nbsp;" .$pieces[2]);
     array_splice($pieces,0,3,$temp);
     break;
   default:
     // 8 col table;     
  }
  return $pieces;
}

$arr = file("whspdel.txt");
foreach($arr as $e){
  $lines[] = preg_replace('!\s!', ',', $e);
}

echo <<<THEAD
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<thead><th>Location</th><th>State</th><th>High</th><th>Low</th><th>Days Clear</th>
<th>Days Cloudy</th><th>Days with Preceipitation</th><th>Days with Snow</th>
THEAD;

$data = array_map("str_getcsv", $lines);
foreach($data as $row) {
  $i=0;
  echo "<tr>\n";
  $better_row = join(" ",$row);
  $split = fixCities($better_row);
  foreach ($split as $e) {
     if ($e == "") continue;
     if ($i==0){
        echo "<td class='left'>",$e,"</td>";
        $i++;
     }
     else
     {
        echo "<td class='phpcolor'>",$e,"</td>";
     }
  }
  echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
?>
```

converts the OP's text file into an HTML table, as depicted below:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
width:80%;
border:1px solid #fff;
box-shadow: -18px -8px 20px #ccc;
margin-left:13%;
}
tr {
width: 100%;
}
td {
  background:transparent;
  width:10%;
  border-top:1px solid #003;
  border-right:none;
  border-left:none;
  font: 62% Arial,Helvetica;
  padding:6px;
  text-align:right;
}
th {
font: 62% Arial,Helvetica;
}
.left {
text-align:left;
background:#ffdede;
}
.phpcolor {
background:#ccccff;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<thead><th>Location</th>
    <th>State</th><th>High</th><th>Low</th><th>Days Clear</th>
    <th>Days Cloudy</th><th>Days with Preceipitation</th><th>Days with Snow</th>
<tr>
<td class='left'>Lander</td><td class='phpcolor'>WY</td><td class='phpcolor'>5557</td><td class='phpcolor'>99</td><td class='phpcolor'>-35</td><td class='phpcolor'>109</td><td class='phpcolor'>140</td><td class='phpcolor'>67</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class='left'>Milwaukee</td><td class='phpcolor'>WI</td><td class='phpcolor'>672</td><td class='phpcolor'>98</td><td class='phpcolor'>-7</td><td class='phpcolor'>79</td><td class='phpcolor'>177</td><td class='phpcolor'>124</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class='left'>Seattle</td><td class='phpcolor'>WA</td><td class='phpcolor'>400</td><td class='phpcolor'>94</td><td class='phpcolor'>12</td><td class='phpcolor'>55</td><td class='phpcolor'>233</td><td class='phpcolor'>163</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class='left'>Spokane</td><td class='phpcolor'>WA</td><td class='phpcolor'>2356</td><td class='phpcolor'>98</td><td class='phpcolor'>-16</td><td class='phpcolor'>95</td><td class='phpcolor'>187</td><td class='phpcolor'>112</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class='left'>Burlington</td><td class='phpcolor'>VT</td><td class='phpcolor'>332</td><td class='phpcolor'>91</td><td class='phpcolor'>6</td><td class='phpcolor'>54</td><td class='phpcolor'>217</td><td class='phpcolor'>168</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class='left'>Norfolk</td><td class='phpcolor'>VA</td><td class='phpcolor'>24</td><td class='phpcolor'>98</td><td class='phpcolor'>19</td><td class='phpcolor'>85</td><td class='phpcolor'>145</td><td class='phpcolor'>117</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class='left'>Richmond</td><td class='phpcolor'>VA</td><td class='phpcolor'>164</td><td class='phpcolor'>101</td><td class='phpcolor'>16</td><td class='phpcolor'>105</td><td class='phpcolor'>165</td><td class='phpcolor'>115</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class='left'>Salt&nbsp;Lake&nbsp;City</td><td class='phpcolor'>UT</td><td class='phpcolor'>4221</td><td class='phpcolor'>103</td><td class='phpcolor'>-11</td><td class='phpcolor'>129</td><td class='phpcolor'>152</td><td class='phpcolor'>86</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class='left'>Dallas</td><td class='phpcolor'>TX</td><td class='phpcolor'>551</td><td class='phpcolor'>106</td><td class='phpcolor'>10</td><td class='phpcolor'>130</td><td class='phpcolor'>152</td><td class='phpcolor'>89</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class='left'>Houston</td><td class='phpcolor'>TX</td><td class='phpcolor'>96</td><td class='phpcolor'>104</td><td class='phpcolor'>19</td><td class='phpcolor'>73</td><td class='phpcolor'>166</td><td class='phpcolor'>94</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class='left'>San&nbsp;Antonio</td><td class='phpcolor'>TX</td><td class='phpcolor'>788</td><td class='phpcolor'>102</td><td class='phpcolor'>16</td><td class='phpcolor'>90</td><td class='phpcolor'>165</td><td class='phpcolor'>83</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class='left'>Memphis</td><td class='phpcolor'>TN</td><td class='phpcolor'>258</td><td class='phpcolor'>101</td><td class='phpcolor'>12</td><td class='phpcolor'>121</td><td class='phpcolor'>151</td><td class='phpcolor'>112</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class='left'>Huron</td><td class='phpcolor'>SD</td><td class='phpcolor'>1281</td><td class='phpcolor'>100</td><td class='phpcolor'>-30</td><td class='phpcolor'>121</td><td class='phpcolor'>147</td><td class='phpcolor'>80</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class='left'>Rapid&nbsp;City</td><td class='phpcolor'>SD</td><td class='phpcolor'>3162</td><td class='phpcolor'>106</td><td class='phpcolor'>-30</td><td class='phpcolor'>106</td><td class='phpcolor'>127</td><td class='phpcolor'>95</td></tr>
</table>
 
</body>
</html>
```

One of the challenges with the data is that it was not in a CSV format.  Some of the items were followed by multiple white space characters while others with one or two.  So, my first thought was to reduce those characters and then convert the document to a CSV format.

Using array_map() provides a great convenience: avoids having to construct a for-loop and it speedily applies str_getcsv() to every line of the text file.

`preg_replace()` very helpful in replacing the excessive whitespace characters and the HTML entity `&nbsp;`came in handy for use with the city names consisting of more than one word.

I also use a [heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to good advantage

**Updated:** 
fixCities() now provides a more useful fix for cities out of alignment because their names consist of two or three words. Took a cue from @Chizzele as regards splicing to get the city names into proper alignment.